# What does equipartition of modes mean in ray optics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, refraction, geometric-optics, ergodicity

Consider light as rays interacting with refractive boundaries - no polarization or diffraction, but with scattering - a fixed probability of a ray changing angle per unit time.

First of all, what would be defined as a mode? The trajectory of a ray? Then does a ray that reflects off a surface count as one or two modes? Or is a mode just a point and angle in space that a ray may occupy? And how would one define the density of a mode?

Then what could equipartition of modes mean in this context? This term is usually used to describe things like vibrational and kinetic modes of molecules. Perhaps equipartition could mean equal density of ray angles in any small volume, i.e. homogeneity and isotropy.

I guess there are multiple answers to these questions.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing.

Modes are independent degrees of freedom of the Hamiltonian for system in equilibrium with thermal bath. What is your Hamiltonian? What is your bath? Is your system in thermal equilibrium (black body radiation)? You may stretch the definitions of your system to show resemblance to equipartition law, but that's surely note what people mean by it.

Moreover, equipartition, as the name may wrongly suggest, is not equal partitioning of energy in degrees of freedom. Read Tolman's original article (which is very good).

- Tolman, Richard C. "A general theory of energy partition with applications to quantum theory." Physical Review 11.4 (1918): 261.

Comment: Would diffuse illumination on a refracting boundary from one side be a thermal bath?